# Are these 3 queries close to being correct?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 queries with below based on what I think works. I am not an sql pro and these are for my last homework assignment.

-Reduce by 10% the price of products having at least two offers | 'Tb_Offers.Prod_ID' ... AGGREGATE function or GROUP BY clause

```
UPDATE Tb_Offers
SET Price=CASE
WHEN Prod_ID IN (SELECT Prod_ID FROM Tb_Offers
HAVING COUNT(Tb_Offers.Prod_ID)>1) THEN 0.9
ELSE 1
END*Price
```

-
     Delete all offers for which there are no sales | Says (0 rows affected)

```
DELETE Tb_Offers
WHERE Prod_ID NOT IN (SELECT Tb_Product.Prod_ID FROM Tb_Transactions, Tb_Product, Tb_Offers
WHERE Tb_Product.Prod_ID = Tb_Offers.Prod_ID
AND Tb_Offers.Prod_ID = Tb_Transactions.Prod_ID)
```

-
    Reduce by 20% computer prices and prices for products having at least 4 offers | 'Tb_Offers.Prod_ID' ... AGGREGATE function or GROUP BY clause

```
UPDATE Tb_Offers
SET Price=.20*Price
WHERE Prod_ID IN
(SELECT Prod_ID
FROM Tb_Product P
WHERE CASE
WHEN Name='Computer' THEN 1
ELSE (SELECT Prod_ID
FROM Tb_Offers O
HAVING COUNT(Prod_ID)>=4)
END=1)
```

**I have the following tables:**

Tb_Consumer - Name, City, Con_ID
Tb_Supplier - Name, City, Supp_ID
Tb_Offers - Name, Quantity, Prod_ID, Supp_ID
Tb_Product - Name, Prod_ID
Tb_Requests - Name, Quantity, Prod_ID, Con_ID
Tb_Transactions - Prod_ID, Tran_ID, Supp_ID, Con_ID, Quantity, Price

Comment: Q1: always read the question carefully: "Reduce by 10% the price of products **having at least two offers**" so you need to count by prod_id in Tb_**Offers**

Comment: Duh, thanks. How do I go about getting rid of the GROUP BY because now I have that on all 3, I've tried placing it in a few different places

Comment: Q2: where is prod_id in the transactions table? (it isn't shown above) can you use "inner join" instead of that horrible old fashioned comma based joins through a where clause. Surely that isn't being taught any more?

Comment: Q3: looks like a fail to me, not sure what that subquery is attempting. perhaps use `union all` instead

Comment: This is the exact stuff I was taught in class, and this is what he looks for. Also updated Prod_ID in the transactions table, sorry about that.

Comment: extra question by comment, I have no idea what that means as I cannot see your work in progress....

Comment: "he" looks for crap that is non-standard and poor practice? joining in a where clause is as old fashioned as steam cars, and "he" must be older than even I am... and I'm ancient ANSI-92 (1992) formalized "best practice" in joins that's 25 years ago

Comment: I didn't learn this on my own..... He is probably in his late 40's. I've had trouble here and there but never had this type of trouble. Sorry..

Comment: I've never seen an exam question on here that was relevant or up to date. Don't be suprised that this is being taught.

Comment: In the update statement, the column 'price' is set for table 'Tb_Offers' but you don't show this column in the table where you're displaying all your tables.  I only see 'price' in Tb_Transactions?